# What Settings Are Possible on Lightsabers?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

There are training lightsabers, with a low setting so they inflict nothing more than burns or bruises and in *Splinter of the Mind's Eye* I remember Luke setting his lightsaber, at one point, to produce a thin beam to pick a lock or help him get through a door.

What are the different settings most lightsabers (as in a lightsaber your average Jedi might us) that are available?  Is it just in terms of power, or are there other adjustments that can be made?

Comment: I know nothing about non-film Star Wars, but wasn't Luke's lightsaber custom-made by himself? Pre-Clonewars ready-made sabers don't necessarily have that feature, only because Luke's did.

Comment: On, Off, Stun, Vibrate, Mute, Full Auto, Landscape, Macro, Roaming and Defrost.

Comment: You forgot dodge and burn

Comment: IDKFA, IDDQD, I an too young to die and inferno

Comment: @DVK: You're mixing in cheat codes. I think you meant [this](http://doom.wikia.com/wiki/Skill_level). ;)

Comment: +chance on hit to proc seal of command. (ahh those were the days!)

Comment: @DavRob60: You forgot Smite.

Comment: If you press ↑↑↓↓←→←→BA then your enemy dies instantly

Comment: It's a three-position switch, with Off in the middle, Armed when you push the button away from yourself and Harakiri when you pull the button towards yourself.

Comment: @bitmask - Splinter of the Mind's Eye is set between Episode IV and V, so he would still have Anakin's saber at that point.

Comment: @Omegacron: Thank you. I wasn't aware of that. In my defence, I said I had no clue about non-film Star Wars media. :)

Comment: @Richard That must be the Coruscant Code :,)

Comment: The settings are "Ho! Ha ha! Guard! Turn! Parry! Dodge! Spin! Ha! Thrust!" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cuihrjLNAo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes, lightsabers have setting for blade length and blade power.

**From the *[Star Wars: The Visual Dictionary](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Visual_Dictionary)* (now "Legends" continuity)**

[image: lightsaber cross section dictionary]

---

**This is confirmed in *[Star Wars: The Visual Encyclopedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Visual_Encyclopedia)* (main canon)**

[image: lightsaber cross section encyclopedia]

Answer (score 5):

From [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lightsaber_crystal):

> While the Jedi used natural crystals, the Sith often used red-hued synthetic crystals. Sith-made synthetic crystals create a slightly more powerful blade when energized by the dark side of the Force, occasionally demonstrating the ability to "break" Jedi lightsaber blades, disrupting the energy circuit and shorting out the weapon, as almost happened to Obi-Wan Kenobi while fighting Darth Vader on the first Death Star.

From my understanding it isn't so much that standard lightsabers have different "settings", but different lightsaber crystals had differences in purity and strength that performed differently. For example, in the Jedi Acadamy series, [Gantoris](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Gantoris) constructed a dual phase lightsaber that used three [Corusca gems](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Corusca_gem) which allowed him to alter the length of his saber during his demonstration to Luke.

Comment: In the expanded universe, it's usually reported that lightsabers do indeed have multiple settings. I don't have the resources to forma a proper answer, however.

Comment: Indeed, as example Corran Horn kills a Yuuzhan Vong enemy by extending his blade and thus instantly penetrating his adversaries skull. Now in which of the books was that...